# How to make a function to remove vectors

Tags: r

I'm exercising my function writing skills today. Can someone explain why the function I wrote doesn't remove columns 2 and 3 from the data frame?

```
data <- data.frame(x = 2, y = 3, z = 4)
rmvar <- function(x){
  lapply(X = x, FUN = function(x){
    x <- NULL})}
rmvar(data[,2:3])
```

Comment: Functions perform their actions on copies of the data.

Comment: just one thing: it's confusing to have 'x' argument for both the main and the inside function

Comment: What would `X` be? Also, best way to remove, say, column 2 of a data frame is doing `df[,-2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify it

```
rmvar <- function(x, indx){
  x[indx] <- lapply(x[indx], FUN=function(x) x <- NULL)
  x
 }

rmvar(data, 2:3)
#  x
#1 2
```

As @nico mentioned in the comments, this is easier by just `data[-(2:3)]`.  But, I guess you want to do this with `lapply/NULL`.

Comment: Now look at  `names(data)`

Comment: It is because I didn't assign it.   My understanding is that the OP wanted the output have to some columns removed based on the index.

Comment: @akrun How come I can't put x on the same line as the rest of the function R throws an error if I don't have what's printed on a new line e.g., rmvar <- function(x, indx){x[indx] <- lapply(x[indx], FUN = function(x) {x <- NULL}) return(x)}

Comment: Try `rmvar <- function(x, indx){x[indx] <- lapply(x[indx], FUN=function(x) x <- NULL); x}`